# Solr: Pattern match field names

Tags: solr

Does anyone know if it's possible to write a query to pattern match field names and search fields that start with a certain string? For instance, fields might be named `address01`, `address02`, `address03`, etc. Is it possible to write a query similar to `address*:California`, which is supposed to search through all fields starting with `address`.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You'll want to have a copyField instruction in that case, usually with a wildcard source, that copies everything into an `address_search` field. Something like `copyField source="address*" dest="address_search"`